# Не переведены «Duplicate A» и «Duplicate B» в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, дубликаты

Наткнулся вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/623570

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы. Первые буквы латинского алфавита сопоставил первым буквам
русского алфавита, т.е. A→А, B→Б, C→В, D→Г, E→Д:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15805
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15802
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15797
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15804
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15803

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.7.16.39771